# C# setting the display value of a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, winforms, drop-down-menu, switch-statement

i wish to set the default value of a dropdown list depending on what appears in my table row. i have written the switch statement below but does not seem to do the job. can anyone help ?

```
bool viewNull = this._Row.Isxcs_ViewNull();
if (!viewNull)
{
    switch (this._Row.xcs_View.ToUpper())
    {
        case "RC": this.drpdwnChaseSecSelection.SelectedValue = "Renewals Chasing"; break;
        case "D_RL": this.drpdwnChaseSecSelection.SelectedValue = "Deal - Lettings"; break;
        case "NULL": this.drpdwnChaseSecSelection.SelectedValue = "None"; break;
    }
}
else
{
    drpdwnChaseSecSelection.SelectedValue = "None";
}
```

Comment: What event are you calling it in? Can you expand the code sample a bit more to show some context.

Comment: Are there really only three options for your xcs_View variable? Have you stepped trough your code with the debugger?

Comment: what value does this._Row.xcs_View have when you debug?

Comment: @WouterdeKort I have stepped through the code, when the database value is null,.. it jumps to the else section, but its just not making the None value from the dropdown as a default

Comment: try adding a case default : this.drpdwnChaseSecSelection.SelectedValue = "None"; break; and remove the "NULL" case

Answer (score 2):

Are you databinding the dropdownList? something on the lines of:

```
drpdwnChaseSecSelection.DataSource = GetListItems(); // <-- Get your data from somewhere.
drpdwnChaseSecSelection.DataValueField = "ValueProperty";
drpdwnChaseSecSelection.DataTextField = "TextProperty";

drpdwnChaseSecSelection.DataBind();

bool viewNull = this._Row.Isxcs_ViewNull();
if (!viewNull)
{
    switch (this._Row.xcs_View.ToUpper())
    {
        case "RC": drpdwnChaseSecSelection.SelectedIndex=drpdwnChaseSecSelection.Items.IndexOf(drpdwnChaseSecSelection.Items.FindByText("Renewals Chasing")); break;
        case "D_RL":drpdwnChaseSecSelection.SelectedIndex=drpdwnChaseSecSelection.Items.IndexOf(drpdwnChaseSecSelection.Items.FindByText("Deal - Lettings")); break;
        case default: drpdwnChaseSecSelection.SelectedIndex=drpdwnChaseSecSelection.Items.IndexOf(drpdwnChaseSecSelection.Items.FindByText("None")); break;
    }
}
else
{
    drpdwnChaseSecSelection.SelectedIndex=drpdwnChaseSecSelection.Items.IndexOf(drpdwnChaseSecSelection.Items.FindByText("None"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but it seems like you know the entries at compile time. If that is the case just use the SelectedIndex as 'tranceporter' suggests in his answer but without the search (drpdwnChaseSecSelection.Items.IndexOf(drpdwnChaseSecSelection.Items.FindByText("Renewals Chasing"));)

This will give you better performance.

Answer (score 0):

If these are just string values you can use SelectedItem.

If these are items based on databinding you should connect your ValueMember on the dropdown list to the correct value on your object, then you can use SelectedValue.